# Powershell get top x rows from each file in folder and create sample files

Tags: powershell

I want to create samples of all `.txt` files in a folder. Basically, wanting to copy top 1000 rows from each file within the `\source` folder and dump into sample files in the `\Source\Samples` sub-directory. Trying to keep the sample file name similar to the original but append `__SAMPLE` to the filename. I tried writing the below code but it doesn't work. Most likely it's the `get-content....` line which has an issue. Can someone please help?

```
$sourceDir = "Y:\Source"
$destDir = "Y:\source\Samples"

$myFiles = Get-ChildItem $sourceDir *.txt -rec

foreach ($file in $myFiles)
{
    get-content $file.PSPath -head 1000 | set-content {$file + "__SAMPLE"}.PSPath + "\Samples"

}
```

Comment: `$file |Get-Content |Select -First 1000 |...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you construct the path for `Set-Content` doesn't work like this in PowerShell. The `Join-Path`cmdlet is what you want:

If you do not need to preserve the original folder structure you can do the following:

```
Join-Path -Path $destDir -ChildPath "$($file.BaseName)__SAMPLE$($file.Extension)"
```

This will take `Y:\Source\foo\bar.txt` and turn it into `Y:\source\Samples\bar__SAMPLE.txt`

```
$sourceDir = "Source"
$destDir = "Source\Samples"

$myFiles = Get-ChildItem $sourceDir *.txt -rec

foreach ($file in $myFiles)
{
    $destinationPath = (Join-Path -Path $destDir -ChildPath "$($file.BaseName)__SAMPLE$($file.Extension)")
    get-content $file.PSPath -head 1000 | set-content -Path $destinationPath
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the explanation and the corrected code! :)